# Group by clause in Sql and filtering on an option,

Tags: sql, group-by

I am working on a code, and the columns will something be like

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
10    1    A
10    2    B
11    3    C
11    4    c
```

So i am grouping by Col1 and whereever Col3 =  A i need the whole information for that number of Col1. so in above example,i want the output as

```
Col1 col2 col3
10    1    A
10    2    B
```

Can someone please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` and a correlating subquery to check if a row with the same `col1` and a `col3` of `'A'` exists.

```
SELECT *
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM elbat t2
                            WHERE t2.col1 = t1.col1
                                  AND t2.col3 = 'A');
```

Comment: Can i do the same job with CTE as i have to then join the column 1 to my main query ?